# Lua CLI installation - How do I get the terminal command 'lua' to work on OSX?

Tags: lua, installation, command-line-interface

I just installed Lua and I'm following a tutorial but I'm running into a problem straight off, the tutorial simply says to run a file use the terminal command `$lua filename.lua` When I do try using the command `$lua` I get the error `bash: lua: command not found`. I can't find the CLI command `$lua` addressed anywhere in the Lua docs and it's not addressed in the video. I saw elsewhere that you could just run `$helloworld.lua` in the command line but that gives me the same error.

The exact command I'm running is:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:LuaPractice admin$ lua helloworld.lua
bash: lua: command not found
```

I have successfully installed Lua, following running these commands from lua.org:

```
$curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
$tar zxf lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
$cd lua-5.3.5
$make macosx test
```

Then running `$src/lua -v` and I get this result.

```
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

[Link to the relavent part of the tutorial video](https://youtu.be/iMacxZQMPXs?t=71).

What do I have to do to run lua scripts in the terminal?

EDIT - I figured out if I run `$~/lua-5.3.5/src/lua helloworld.lua` I get the results I was looking for.  This is really inconvenient though so if anyone can tell me how to make the keyword `lua` work by itself I would be grateful.

Comment: Try `sudo make install` to install lua in `/usr/local/bin/`. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html

Comment: @lhf thank you for your answer.  That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was posted by @lhf.

"Try `sudo make install` to install lua in `/usr/local/bin/`. See lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html

– lhf 20 hours ago"

The installation process should have been:

```
$curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
$tar zxf lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
$cd lua-5.3.5
$make macosx test
$sudo make install
```

The docs linked state that it should be `sudo make macosx install` but it worked for me without the `macosx`.  Now the terminal command `lua` works, thank you.